# Use proxy class extends Object to exchange data between agents

Tags: multi-agent

I want to implement multi agent system and need exchange data, between 2 agent. So I want agent1 send to agent2 some data.

According to my research, in java, could be used to proxy class and use puto2aobject method to transfer data to another agent  at same platform. 
But I don't know how to do this.

How use of proxy class and which kind of behaviour should be use. 
So, if I want to program with jade, how can I exchange data between two Agents?

Could Someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MultiAgent System (MAS) is considered a new programming paradigm. There are many languages and platforms, several of them were build over Java. Sometimes you can find Java in your research but it is completely different, Java is an Object Oriented Language.

So, if you want to implement Agents, I suggest you to look for the most popular MAS frameworks, according to [Kravari2015](http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/18/1/11.html) the top ones are: [Jason](http://jason.sourceforge.net/wp/), [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/), [Jadex](https://www.activecomponents.org) and [NetLogo](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/).

If you prefer to code in Java, JADE or Jadex could be a way to start since they are, let's say, Java code over MAS concepts. In the other hand, Jason uses an special language for agents, which is called AgentSpeak. Netlogo also uses an specific language called Logo, is very used to build simulations.

Comment: So, if I want to program with jade,  how can I exchange data between two Agents? Thanks a lot.

Comment: A good way to "make agents talk" is by Contract Net Protocol, you can see here a comparison between jason and jade using CNP https://github.com/cleberjamaral/tp_cnp